# How to use angular.dart 1.0? (dependency not working)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am currently looking into dart (and angular.dart), reading some tutorials and so on.

I am having problems with getting angular.dart 1.0 working. According to this package description: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular#installing

one only has to add angular.dart as a PUB dependency and then can start working with it:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
```

I have done just that, ran `pub get` but the imported file is still not found. My packages directory is somewhat poor, there is no angular.dart in there.

So how do I use angular.dart 1.0?

[image: Angular dart error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your downloaded angular seems broken. You should try to repair your cache with `pub cache repair` (See [pub cache](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache.html))